# Setting up a Hierarchical Multinomial Processing Tree in Stan

Tags: stan

I'm having trouble setting up a Hierarchical Multinomial Processing tree in Stan. As a starting point, I am trying to add a hierarchy to the simple model here:

https://github.com/stan-dev/example-models/blob/master/Bayesian_Cognitive_Modeling/CaseStudies/MPT/MPT_1_Stan.R

I'm not sure why the code does not work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Example Data (Based on Julia syntax):

```
Nsub = 2
Ntrials = 100
FCat = [20 60 20;30 50 20]



data {  
  // Number of subjects 
  int<lower=1> Nsub;   
  // Number of Trials
  int<lower=1> Ntrials;  
   // Data
  int<lower=0,upper=Ntrials> FCat[Nsub,4];  

}
parameters {
  vector<lower=0,upper=1>[Nsub] c;
  vector<lower=0,upper=1>[Nsub] r;
  vector<lower=0,upper=1>[Nsub] u;

  real<lower=0> c_omega;
  real<lower=0> r_omega;
  real<lower=0> u_omega;

  real<lower=0,upper=1> c_kappa;
  real<lower=0,upper=1> r_kappa;
  real<lower=0,upper=1> u_kappa;

} 
transformed parameters {
    simplex[4] theta[Nsub];

    real<lower=0> c_A;
    real<lower=0> c_B;
    real<lower=0> r_A;
    real<lower=0> r_B;
    real<lower=0> u_A;
    real<lower=0> u_B;

    c_A <- c_kappa*c_omega;
    c_B <- (1-c_kappa)*c_omega;
    r_A <- r_kappa*r_omega;
    r_B <- (1-r_kappa)*r_omega;
    u_A <- u_kappa*u_omega;
    u_B <- (1-u_kappa)*u_omega;

    // Create category responses
    for (i in 1:Nsub){
      theta[i,1] <- c[i]*r[i];
      theta[i,2] <- (1 - c[i])*sqrt(u[i]);
      theta[i,3] <- (1 - c[i])*2*u[i]*(1 - u[i]);
      theta[i,4] <- c[i]*(1 - r[i]) + (1 - c[i])*sqrt(1 - u[i]);
    }


}
model {
  // HyperPriors
  c_omega ~ gamma(2,8);
  r_omega ~ gamma(2,8);
  u_omega ~ gamma(2,8);

  c_kappa ~ beta(50,50);
  r_kappa ~ beta(50,50);
  u_kappa ~ beta(70,30);

  // Priors
  c ~ beta(c_A, c_B);
  r ~ beta(r_A, r_B); 
  u ~ beta(u_A, u_B); 
  for (i in 1:Nsub){
        FCat[i] ~ multinomial(theta[i]);
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you encounter any errors? What are your results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sqrt() function just takes square roots of a scalar (real or int), returning a real.

You can use print() to see if your values sum to 1.  Or you can do a test yourself and reject if they don't.  The usual stick-breaking construction for a simplex is given in the manual in the simplex transform.  The usual approach is to take the first value to be between 0 and 1, then the next to be some fraction of what's left (1 - first value), and so on.  We also have softmax built in.  You have to be careful with identifiability with a softmax parameterization --- the priors will matter unless you set one of the inputs to a constant.

Comment: I had a "duh" moment later that day after realizing that I should have used ^2 instead of sqrt(). An embarrassing oversight on my part.  Good to know about the softmax rule and its potential identifiability issues. Thanks, Bob!